# How to convert categorical columns to integer columns in python? (with NaN)

Tags: python, pandas, types, nan

My dataframe is below.

```
id  gender  region  income  a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6  a7  a8  a9  a10
1   male    N        300    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   female  S        500    7   10  10  10  6   6   6   8   5   9
3   male    E        200    6   NaN 9   6   6   NaN 7   7   7   9
4   female  W        100    9   7   7   NaN 7   8   8   8   NaN 5
```

I want to change data type categorical to integer for multiple columns. (a1~a10)
So, I tried the below code, but occurred error as below

```
df.iloc[:, 4: ].astype('int')
```

> ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

How can I covert this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If use pandas 0.24+ is possible use [Nullable integer data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html), also is necessary `.astype(float)` for convert categorical columns to numbers:

```
df.iloc[:, 4: ] = df.iloc[:, 4: ].astype(float).astype("Int64")
print (df)
   id  gender region  income   a1   a2   a3   a4   a5   a6   a7   a8   a9  a10
0   1    male      N     300  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1   2  female      S     500    7   10   10   10    6    6    6    8    5    9
2   3    male      E     200    6  NaN    9    6    6  NaN    7    7    7    9
3   4  female      W     100    9    7    7  NaN    7    8    8    8  NaN    5
```

If necessary replace missing values by most frequent values per columns:

```
df.iloc[:, 4: ] = df.iloc[:, 4: ].fillna(df.iloc[:, 4: ].mode().iloc[0]).astype(int)

print (df)
   id  gender region  income  a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6  a7  a8  a9  a10
0   1    male      N     300   6   7   7   6   6   6   6   8   5    9
1   2  female      S     500   7  10  10  10   6   6   6   8   5    9
2   3    male      E     200   6   7   9   6   6   6   7   7   7    9
3   4  female      W     100   9   7   7   6   7   8   8   8   5    5
```

Comment: TypeError: data type not understood

Comment: @purplecollar - Can you test `df.iloc[:, 4: ] = df.iloc[:, 4: ].astype(float).astype("Int64")` ?

Comment: @purplecollar - add code for replace missing values by mode, answer was edited.

Answer (score 1):

By default `pandas` convert columns with `np.nan` as `float`

**For pandas version 0.24.0 onwards**

Convert required columns into datatype `Int8` which can have `np.nan` values

```
columns = ["A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8","A9","A10"]

df[columns] = df[columns].astype("Int8")

print(df.dtypes)
```

Refer this [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#optional-integer-na-support)

**Alternate solution**

you can replace `np.nan` with `mode` of each column and then convert them into `int`

```
for c in columns:
    x = df[c].mode()
    x = list(x)[0]
    df[c] = df[c].fillna(x).astype("int")
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I tired above but occurred TypeError: data type not understood

Comment: TypeError occurred.
      1 for c in list2:
      2     x = df[c].mode()
----> 3     x = list2(x)[0]
      4     df[c] = df[c].fillna(x).astype("int")

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: it's `list` not `list2` in line `x = list2(x)[0]`

Comment: I revised list2 to list, but still has error follow: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: you must be having variable name `list`. `list` is a function. change variable name to something else

Answer (score 0):

You have to proceed to a drop a or fill a before.

```
#will remove line with Nan inside
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Or

```
#will replace Nan by a value e.g "- 1" 
df.fillna(-1,inplace=True)
```

Comment: I tried your code but occurred error "fill value must be in categories"

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can follow below approach:

This will fill NaN values with 0, hence the type will be int.

```
df.fillna(value=int(), inplace=True)
```

**or**

This will fill NaN values with `<class 'int'>`, this is also int type.

```
df.fillna(value=int, inplace=True)
```

Comment: ValueError: fill value must be in categories

Answer (score 0):

assume there are no null value in A1-A3 columns

```
cleanup_nums = {"A1":{"Apple":1, "Samsung":2}}
df.replace(cleanup_nums,inplace=True)
```

the detail of `replace` function can refer to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html.

There are also tutorials for encoding categorical values in python. 
https://pbpython.com/categorical-encoding.html